# "return" considered outside the function

Tags: python, syntax-error

For the class below, I'm getting this exception:

```
return probe.GetOutput().GetPointData().GetArray('ImageScalars')
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

Why is Python considering "return" outside the function? Is it an indentation issue? Thanks.

```
def probeVolume(self,volumeNode,rulerNode):
  # get ruler endpoints coordinates in RAS 
    p0ras = rulerNode.GetPolyData().GetPoint(0)+(1,)
    p1ras = rulerNode.GetPolyData().GetPoint(1)+(1,)

  # Convert RAS to IJK coordinates of the vtkImageData
  ras2ijk = vtk.vtkMatrix4x4()
  volumeNode.GetRASToIJKMatrix(ras2ijk)
  p0ijk = [int(round(c)) for c in ras2ijk.MultiplyPoint(p0ras)[:3]]
  p1ijk = [int(round(c)) for c in ras2ijk.MultiplyPoint(p1ras)[:3]]

    # Create VTK line that will be used for sampling
  line = vtk.vtkLineSource()
  line.SetResolution(100)
  line.SetPoint1(p0ijk[0],p0ijk[1],p0ijk[2])
  line.SetPoint2(p1ijk[0],p1ijk[1],p1ijk[2])

    # Create VTK probe filter and sample the image
  probe = vtk.vtkProbeFilter()
  probe.SetInputConnection(line.GetOutputPort())
  probe.SetSourceData(volumeNode.GetImageData())
  probe.Update()

    # return VTK array 
  return probe.GetOutput().GetPointData().GetArray('ImageScalars')
```

Comment: Is your indentation like in the posted code? If yes, this will be the problem

Comment: Your indentation looks inconsistent, can you try to correct it

Comment: Again...Indentation issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an indentation error. The first two lines of the function are double-indented.

Fix:

```
def probeVolume(self,volumeNode,rulerNode):
  # get ruler endpoints coordinates in RAS 
  p0ras = rulerNode.GetPolyData().GetPoint(0)+(1,)
  p1ras = rulerNode.GetPolyData().GetPoint(1)+(1,)

  # Convert RAS to IJK coordinates of the vtkImageData
  ras2ijk = vtk.vtkMatrix4x4()
  volumeNode.GetRASToIJKMatrix(ras2ijk)
  p0ijk = [int(round(c)) for c in ras2ijk.MultiplyPoint(p0ras)[:3]]
  p1ijk = [int(round(c)) for c in ras2ijk.MultiplyPoint(p1ras)[:3]]

    # Create VTK line that will be used for sampling
  line = vtk.vtkLineSource()
  line.SetResolution(100)
  line.SetPoint1(p0ijk[0],p0ijk[1],p0ijk[2])
  line.SetPoint2(p1ijk[0],p1ijk[1],p1ijk[2])

    # Create VTK probe filter and sample the image
  probe = vtk.vtkProbeFilter()
  probe.SetInputConnection(line.GetOutputPort())
  probe.SetSourceData(volumeNode.GetImageData())
  probe.Update()

    # return VTK array 
  return probe.GetOutput().GetPointData().GetArray('ImageScalars')
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your inconsistency of indentation. Python depends on indentation to determine code blocks. To fix the problem, you'll need to indent all of the code in your `probeVolume` function by the same amount.

Answer (score 1):

The first two lines of the function have 4 spaces from the function

```
def probeVolume(self,volumeNode,rulerNode):
  # get ruler endpoints coordinates in RAS 
    p0ras = rulerNode.GetPolyData().GetPoint(0)+(1,)
    p1ras = rulerNode.GetPolyData().GetPoint(1)+(1,)
```

I am not 100% sure if this is the issue , but try indenting the 3rd and 4th line with 2 spaces. Example -

```
def probeVolume(self,volumeNode,rulerNode):
  # get ruler endpoints coordinates in RAS 
  p0ras = rulerNode.GetPolyData().GetPoint(0)+(1,)
  p1ras = rulerNode.GetPolyData().GetPoint(1)+(1,)
```